# PHP: Group Multidimensional array objects based on multiple keys

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Im trying to loop through an array and group object based on a number of keys.
I've tried searching but I don't think I'm using the right search terms.

The arrays contain genealogical data, mother and father names, surnames, etc.
Some objects in the $births array are clearly related to each other as they have the same mother, father, surnames etc and I would like to group them in a new $families array.

Below outlines the type of data and what I would like to achieve.
Any idea on how I can do this? I'm at a loss for how to approach it,

```
$births = Array (
   [1] => Array  (
            [mother_surname] => Pig
            [mother_firstname] => Mommy
            [father_surname] => Pig
            [father_firstname] => Daddy
            [birth_date] => 2005
            [child_firstname] => Peppa
         )
   [2] => Array  (
            [mother_surname] => Pig
            [mother_firstname] => Mommy
            [father_surname] => Pig
            [father_firstname] => Daddy
            [birth_date] => 2008
            [child_firstname] => George
         )
   [3] => Array  (
            [mother_surname] => Cat
            [mother_firstname] => Mrs
            [father_surname] => Cat
            [father_firstname] => Mr
            [birth_date] => 2005
            [child_firstname] => Candy
         )
)


$families = Array (
   [1] => Array  (
              [1] => Array  (
                [mother_surname] => Pig
                [mother_firstname] => Mommy
                [father_surname] => Pig
                [father_firstname] => Daddy
                [birth_date] => 2005
                [child_firstname] => Peppa
              )
              [2] => Array  (
                [mother_surname] => Pig
                [mother_firstname] => Mommy
                [father_surname] => Pig
                [father_firstname] => Daddy
                [birth_date] => 2008
                [child_firstname] => George
              )
         )
   [2] => Array  (
            [mother_surname] => Cat
            [mother_firstname] => Mrs
            [father_surname] => Cat
            [father_firstname] => Mr
            [birth_date] => 2005
            [child_firstname] => Candy
         )
)
```

The closest I've come is:

```
$shiftArray = array_shift($births);
foreach($births as $birth){
      print_r(  array_intersect($shiftArray, $birth)  );
}
```

But that's a failure.

Comment: In what is it a failure ? What does it return ?

Comment: So you have the `births` array and want to accumulate the `families` array? That given, all mother/father names have to be unique - otherwise this will fail without any unique identifier, like an `ID`.

Comment: will changing the family key from a number to the family surname be allowed?  If that is the case just walk through the births and add them to `families[$surname][]`.  Also, can parent's have different surnames like Poppa Horse and Momma Mule.  And can multiple families have the same surname only differentiated by the parent's firstnames?

Comment: @Azrael_404 The dataset is orientated around a specific surname in a specific location and covers a range of about 120 years. It's a failure because it seems to return only the common aspects in the $births array, essentially the Surnames, as that is what is common to the dataset. What I need to do is go through the $births array and see which ones have specific values in common, parents firstnames and surnames and then group them as siblings in a new $families array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tyson you put me on the right track, thank you!
Here is my solution, in case it is of benefit to anyone else.
It also takes into account the family address, not referenced in my original question.

```
$families = array();
function searchForChildren($MSN,$MFN,$FSN,$FFN,$ADD,$array) {
    global $families;
    $stack = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if ($val['Mother_Surname'] == $MSN && $val['Mother_Firstname'] == $MFN && $val['Father_Surname'] == $FSN && $val['Father_Firstname'] == $FFN && $val['Family_Address'] == $ADD) {
            $info = array(
                'Mother_Surname' => $MSN,
                'Mother_Firstname' => $MFN,
                'Father_Surname' => $FSN,
                'Father_Firstname' => $FFN,
                'Family_Address' => $ADD,
                'Birth_Year' => $val['Birth_Year'],
                'Child_Surname' => $val['Child_Surname'],
                'Child_Firstname' =>  $val['Child_Firstname']  
            );
            array_push($stack,$info );
        }
    }
   array_push($families,$stack);
}

//The below function strips out any duplicates from the parents array
function arrayUnique ( $rArray ){ 
    $rReturn = array (); 
    while ( list( $key, $val ) = each ( $rArray ) ){ 
        if ( !in_array( $val, $rReturn ) ) 
        array_push( $rReturn, $val ); 
    } 
    return $rReturn; 
} 
$uniqueParents = arrayUnique($parents);

foreach($uniqueParents as $parents){ 
    $MSN = $parents['Mother_Surname'];
    $MFN = $parents['Mother_Firstname'];
    $FSN = $parents['Father_Surname'];
    $FFN = $parents['Father_Firstname'];
    $ADD = $parents['Family_Address'];
    searchForChildren($MSN,$MFN,$FSN,$FFN,$ADD, $births);
}
print_r(json_encode($families));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may need a third array, the $family_pattern array. Here is some pseudocode that may help

```
walk through births
  filter $parents_info from birth (father_surname, father_firstname, mother)surname, mother_firstname)
  if($parents_info in $family_pattern get $key)
    $families[$key][] = $birth
  else
    $family_pattern[] = $parents_info
    $key = $family_pattern count - 1 
    $families[$key][] = $birth
```

Comment: I think your on the right track with this! I'll let you know how I get on, thanks Tyson.